# WindowManagerBadTokenException in android activitygroup

Tags: android

I am trying to call a webservice but nothing is happening on button click.I am using 
activtygroup I have tried both type of contexts child and parent but its not working.
It is showing **WindowManagerBadTokenException**.

**Here is my code to call webservice:**

```
//GET USER WEBSERVICE
    public void callUpdateUserInfo_WS() {

        if (NetworkAvailablity.checkNetworkStatus(ProfileScreen.this)) {
            // PREPARE URL
            Constant.methodURL = "http://admin.tvdevphp.com/goalmachine/update_profile.php";

            // PREPARE REQUEST PARAMETER
            ArrayList<NameValuePair> requestParaList = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();

            requestParaList.add(new BasicNameValuePair("user_id", "1"));
            requestParaList.add(new BasicNameValuePair("first_name", "Ricky"));
            requestParaList.add(new BasicNameValuePair("age", "0"));
            requestParaList.add(new BasicNameValuePair("age_visible", "Yes"));
            requestParaList.add(new BasicNameValuePair("parental_status", "Yes"));
            requestParaList.add(new BasicNameValuePair("parental_status_visible", "Yes"));
            requestParaList.add(new BasicNameValuePair("marital_status", "Single"));
            requestParaList.add(new BasicNameValuePair("marital_status_visible", "No"));
            requestParaList.add(new BasicNameValuePair("short_bio", "Hard working"));
            requestParaList.add(new BasicNameValuePair("short_bio_visible", "Yes"));
            requestParaList.add(new BasicNameValuePair("country", "India"));

            requestParaList.add(new BasicNameValuePair("country_visible", "Yes"));
            requestParaList.add(new BasicNameValuePair("zipcode", "452001"));
            requestParaList.add(new BasicNameValuePair("zipcode_visible", "Yes"));
            requestParaList.add(new BasicNameValuePair("avatar", ""));

            requestParaList.add(new BasicNameValuePair("latest_status_update", "In Indore India."));
            requestParaList.add(new BasicNameValuePair("latest_status_update_visible", "Yes"));
            requestParaList.add(new BasicNameValuePair("pain_scale", "50"));
            requestParaList.add(new BasicNameValuePair("pain_scale_visible", "No"));

            // CALL WEBSERVICE
            WebServiceCommunicator.getInstance().registerForServerResponse(
                    (IServerResponse)this.getParent());
            WebServiceCommunicator.getInstance().callGetAppWebService(
                    Constant.showDialog, this.getParent(),
                    Constant.methodURL, this.getParent(), Constant.PID_UPDATE_USER_INFO,
                    false, requestParaList);
        } else {
            Constant.showAlertDialog(Constant.errorTitle,
                    Constant.MSG_CHECK_INTERNET_SETTING, this.getParent(),
                    false);
        }
    }
```

**This is webservice stuff:**

```
public void callGetAppWebService(final Boolean showProgressBar,
            final Context childContext, final String url,
            final Context context, final int processid,
            final boolean isFinishForFailResponse,
            final ArrayList<NameValuePair> requestParaList) {
        if (_progressDialog != null && _progressDialog.isShowing()) {
            _progressDialog.cancel();
        }
        if (showProgressBar) {
            _progressDialog = ProgressDialog
                    .show(context, "", "Please wait...");

        }
        _context = childContext;
        _isFinishForFailResponse = isFinishForFailResponse;
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                Looper.prepare();
                try {
                    if (NetworkAvailablity.checkNetworkStatus(context)) {
                        String jsonResponse = WebService.postData(url,
                                requestParaList);
                        if (jsonResponse != null && jsonResponse.length() != 0) {
                            strResponse = jsonResponse;
                            Log.v("response", strResponse);
                        }

                    } else {

                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    // DebugLog.LOGE("Exception from callWebService():" +
                    // e.toString());
                }
                if (showProgressBar)
                    _progressDialog.cancel();
                handleResponse(strResponse, processid);
            }
        }).start();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume this is because in your `Thread` you are trying to cancel the `progressDialog`. 
Android won't allow you modify the UI thread from another thread.

A better approach would be to use an [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) (instead of Thread), and override the 3 methods:

`onPreExecute()` - show the dialog, runs on UI thread
`doInBackground()` - make the http request, runs in a separate thread
`onPostExecute()` - hide the dialog, runs on UI thread.

Search in Google, there are plenty of examples how to use `AsyncTask`.